# How to add a Date Selector to Chartjs in the context of Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I am new to Vuejs, i have implemented chart using Chartjs, i want to add date selector to my chartjs. I have used 4 buttons, so whenever i click any of the button my chart should change accordingly.

Initially i tried implementing each button with each method, but i don't feel that as an effective way to do so.

```
> Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/95kspb70/3/
```

I want the chart to change when ever i click any of the button that i have used, i mean i have used 4 buttons, suppose say i clicked 3m, my chart should show previous 3months data only.

Please help me with this, I don't know how exactly i should do it in order to solve this.

Comment: you should mention what type of change you need

Comment: I want the chart to change when ever i click any of the button that i have used, i mean i have used 4 buttons, suppose say i clicked 3m, my chart should show previous 3months data only.

Comment: For example: https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/zxrkh502/ this is done using canvas.js, i am looking for similar results in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the data based on the date and rerender the chart for the new data.
Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7zaoxnt/)
I add click event `@click="selectPeriod"` inside html:

```
<div id='app'>
  <div id="range-selector">
    <input type="button" id="1m" @click="selectPeriod" class="period ui-button" value="1m" />
    <input type="button" id="3m" @click="selectPeriod" class="period ui-button" value="3m" />
    <input type="button" id="6m" @click="selectPeriod" class="period ui-button" value="6m" />
    <input type="button" id="all" @click="selectPeriod" class="period ui-button" value="All" />
  </div>
  <canvas ref='chart' width='800' height='600'></canvas>
</div>
```

and following js code:

```
new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    date: [
      1567295500.0,
      1567893700.0,
      1568615220.0,
      1569024000.0,
      1569888120.0,
      1572456400.0,
      1572772560.0,
      1574809200.0,
      1576706160.0,
      1577718000.0,
      1578610800.0,
      1582650220.0,
      1583174000.0,
      1584063360.0,
      1587427200.0,
      1587573420.0,
      1588637800.0,
      1589587420.0,
      1589989800.0

    ],
    challenge: [
      0.45,
      2.12,
      2.55,
      3.15,
      4.16,
      5.56,
      6.258,
      7.256,
      8.364,
      9.154,
      10.245,
      11.654,
      12.364,
      13.785,
      14,
      15.32,
      16.87,
      17.852,
      18.254,
      19
    ],
    data: []
  }),

  mounted() {
    this.data = this.date.map((date, index) => ({
      x: new Date(date * 1000),
      y: this.challenge[index]
    }))
    this.buildGraph(this.data);
  },
  methods: {
    buildGraph(data) {
      console.log(data.length);
      let ctx = this.$refs.chart.getContext('2d')
      let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            data
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                unit: 'month',
                displayFormats: {
                  month: 'MMM YYYY'
                }
              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  return value + 'k';
                }
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      })
    },

    selectPeriod(event) {
      let period = event.target.value;
      let minValue = new Date(Math.max(...this.date) * 1000);
      let axisXMin = new Date(Math.min(...this.date) * 1000);

      switch (period) {
        case "1m":
          minValue.setMonth(minValue.getMonth() - 1);
          break;
        case "3m":
          minValue.setMonth(minValue.getMonth() - 3);
          break;
        case "6m":
          minValue.setMonth(minValue.getMonth() - 6);
          break;
        case "1y":
          minValue.setYear(minValue.getFullYear() - 1);
          break;
        default:
          minValue = axisXMin;
      }
      let data = this.data.filter(el => {
        return el.x >= minValue
      });
      this.buildGraph(data);
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works, but actually i am fetching my data using API and here how i have done it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65473904/unable-to-get-date-selection-in-chartjs-in-the-context-of-vuejs Please help me with that, because i am unable to solve it.

Comment: can you please help me in this.

Comment: sorry for the late

Comment: No problem at all, i should really appreciate you, for making your time in order to solve my issue.

Comment: Hello @tuhin47, hope your doing well, i wanted to implement the YTD logic for date selection here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65914318/vuejs-how-to-implement-the-ytd-year-to-date-logic-in-order-to-do-date-select , please do help me because i did not find any logic regarding this.