# How to handle the axios errors in the context of Vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

I want to display/print 'Disabled' when ever my API returns any error and display 'Enabled' when it is returning successfully with 200 ok status.

Here's what my API is returning:

[image]

So, my API is returning error currently, so i want to print/display 'Disabled'.

Here how i did it:

```
<template>
      <div class="api_data">
        <span class="trick_not_ok" v-if="error" >{{error}}</span>
        <span class="trick_ok" v-if="noerror" >{{noerror}}</span>
      </div>
</template>
    
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
      name: Api_data,
      data () {
        return {
          error: [],
          noerror: []
        }
      },
      created() {
        axios.get('...URL...')
          .then((response) => { 
               console.log(response.data)
               this.noerror = 'Enabled' 
           })
          .catch((error) => { 
               if (error) {
                   console.log(error)
                   this.error = 'Disabled'
               }  
          })
      }
    }
    </script>
```

But nothing is printed/displayed on my screen, and i am getting error in my console as **GET ...URL... 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)**, How do i display 'Disabled' when my API returns error and 'Enabled' when my API is returning successfully.

Note: I have also tried in .catch as if (error.response.stastus) and if (error.status) but both did not work and i am getting the same error in my console.

Someone please do help me with this.

Comment: share the screenshot of error

Comment: It says this GET ......URL...... 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)

Answer (score 1):

Here
is a codepen solution that I'd use for your trouble. Using boolean for selecting the status and then string for the message you want to display.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
        return {
          isError: false,
          noerror: false,
          message:'loading'
        }
      },
      created() {
        axios.get('...URL...')
          .then((response) => { 
               console.log(response.data)
               this.noerror = true 
               this.message = 'enabled' 
           })
          .catch((error) => { 
               if (error) {
                   console.log(error)
                   this.isError = true
                   this.message = 'disabled'
               }  
          })
      },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="api_data">
    <span class="trick_not_ok" v-if="isError">{{message}}</span>
    <span class="trick_ok" v-if="noerror">{{message}}</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: let me know if it helped.. I'm curious.

Comment: Not working getting the same error what i have mentioned in my Question. You have any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to the code to understand what this status is,

```
switch(status) { case 401: message = 'UNAUTHORIZED'; break ...}
```

or from api you send a json for error message and return by error.response.data.message for this json:

```
{"message": "UNAUTHORIZED"}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what changes should i make in my code?

Comment: @Quantum give an example for the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok. Here is the working demo.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#api_data",
  data() {
    return {
      error: null,
      noerror: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('https://api.bonsai.io/clusters')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.noerror = 'Enabled'
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error) {
          this.error = 'Disabled'
        }
      })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="api_data">
  <span class="trick_not_ok" v-if="error">{{error}}</span>
  <span class="trick_ok" v-if="noerror">{{noerror}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: edited my answer. your code works fine to me.

Comment: Then, I guess some issue is with the API only.

Comment: can you please give me some ideas for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502413/how-can-i-have-single-vue-component-and-how-each-contents-in-that-can-be-routed

Comment: Hello @tuhin47, can you please give me some ideas regarding these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502413/how-can-i-have-single-vue-component-and-how-each-contents-in-that-can-be-routed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502413/how-can-i-have-single-vue-component-and-how-each-contents-in-that-can-be-routed. Please do help me, because your ideas are working.