# How can I have single Vue component and how each contents in that can be routed by buttons of other component

Tags: vue.js, routes, components

I am new to Vuejs, I am looking to make my code effective just by having one vue component, and i want to specify the routing only once.

Currently i have one info.vue in a apps directive and prises.vue & priseshigh.vue in more directive. I want to have just one component in more directive. But the problem is in info.vue i have used two buttons, each button routes to prises.vue & priseshigh.vue respectively. Just like below code:

```
<vs-button class="btn"  @click="$router.push({name: 'prises'}).catch(err => {})" >Go To</vs-button>
<vs-button class="btn"  @click="$router.push({name: 'priseshigh'}).catch(err => {})" >Go There</vs-button>
```

My first question: So now i want to know, if i make one component as prisescomplete.vue by combining prises.vue & priseshigh.vue, how do i specify the routing to the buttons respectively in info.vue And what should i use in the prisescomplete.vue component to route the prises.vue & priseshigh.vue contents respectively .

My second question: below is my routing.js, so now what changes should i make in routing if i just have one component in views directive, and also with respect to first question.

```
       {
          path: '/apps/info',
          name: 'info',
          component: () => import('./views/apps/info/Info.vue'),
          meta: {
            rule: 'editor',
            no_scroll: true
          }
        },
        {
          path: '/apps/info/info-more/prises-card',
          name: 'prises',
          component: () => import('./views/apps/info/more/prises.vue'),
          meta: {
            pageTitle: 'info-more',
            rule: 'editor',
            no_scroll: true
          }
        },
        {
          path: '/apps/info/info-more/priseshigh-card',
          name: 'priseshigh',
          component: () => import('./views/apps/info/more/priseshigh.vue'),
          meta: {
            pageTitle: 'info-more',
            rule: 'editor',
            no_scroll: true
          }
        },
```

Please send me the modified code, so that i can understand it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass **props** to route components.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

```js
{
    path: '/apps/info/info-more/prises-card',
    name: 'prises',
    component: () => import('./views/apps/info/more/prisescomplete.vue'),
    props: {
        prisesType: "prises"
    },
     meta: {
            rule: 'editor'
          }
 },
 {
    path: '/apps/info/info-more/priseshigh-card',
    name: 'priseshigh',
    component: () => import('./views/apps/info/more/prisescomplete.vue'),
    props: {
        prisesType: "priseshigh"
    },
     meta: {
            rule: 'editor'
          }
    }
```

PrisesComplete.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-if="prisesType === 'prises'"> Prises </span>
    <span v-else-if="prisesType === 'priseshigh'"> Prises High </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PrisesComplete",
  props: {
    prisesType: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, you could use `to="/path"`

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html

```js
<vs-button class="btn" :to="{ name: 'prises' }"> Go To </vs-button>
<vs-button class="btn" :to="{ name: 'priseshigh' }"> Go There </vs-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to write a `navigation.vue` component for the navigation and render inside app with `routerview`. Look the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-sending-props-12-forked-cunnk?file=/src/App.js) and the describtion

**TheNavigation.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vs-button
      class="btn"
      @click="$router.push({ name: 'prises' }).catch((err) => {})"
      >Prises</vs-button
    >
    <vs-button
      class="btn"
      @click="$router.push({ name: 'priseshigh' }).catch((err) => {})"
      >Priseshigh</vs-button
    >
  </div>
</template>
```

then render the navigation bar with the router view for loading the router.Here is the
**App.vue** where you render the navigation and routerview.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <TheNavigation/>
    <hr>
    <RouterView/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TheNavigation from "./components/TheNavigation";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    TheNavigation
  }
};
</script>
```

RouterView is reponsible for loading the components which are defined inside router.js
Here is the **Router.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/prises-card",
      name: "prises",
      component: () => import("./components/Prises.vue"),
      meta: {
        pageTitle: "info-more",
        rule: "editor",
        no_scroll: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/priseshigh-card",
      name: "priseshigh",
      component: () => import("./components/PrisesHigh.vue"),
      meta: {
        pageTitle: "info-more",
        rule: "editor",
        no_scroll: true
      }
    }
  ]
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but this is not what i am looking for. I have Info.vue component which is displayed in my browser. It  contains two buttons in it. So when ever i click the first button it navigates to prises.vue and second button will navigate to priseshigh.vue. Now i want to combine this prises.vue and priseshigh.vue as one component and name it as prisescomplete.vue. Now my buttons should still navigate the content of prises & priseshigh which is in prisescomplete. So what changes should i do in my routerlink & in my buttons  and also how to specify the contents in prisescomplete.

Comment: if i'm not wrong.. you need to add a new router for your prisescomple.vue component. is it??

Comment: yes, and how to route specific content from prisescomplete.vue. As i said you earlier if i click my buttons in info.vue it goes to prises and priseshigh respectively. But the content of prises and priseshigh are made one as prisescomplete. So i want to know what routing i should change  and how i can route the specific content from prisescomplete to the buttons.

Comment: Hello, tuhin47 i got that by myself, from your answer i understood how the things work and how routing happens in practical. Now can you give me some ideas for this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518724/how-do-i-display-different-charts-from-single-method-and-how-i-can-import-that-t

Comment: Hello @tuhin47, i have an issue regarding the chartjs, i think you may have some ideas, here is the URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538183/flickering-of-charts-and-getcontext-error-with-chartjs-in-the-context-of-vuejs Please do help me, because so far i have understood all your answers that you have gaven me.