# Flickering of charts and getcontext error with chartjs in the context of Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

Hello i am trying to display different charts using the chartjs by calling the API. Below code shows how i have formatted the chart.vue

**Chart.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height: 40vh; width:100%;">
    <slot name="test1"></slot>
    <slot name="test2"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'charts',
  data () {
    return {
      date: [],
      challenge: [],
      data: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.check(8, 'chart_8')
    this.check(7, 'chart_7')
  },
  methods: {
    check (id, name) {
      this.$http.get(`/api_chart/${ id  }/full`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.date = response.data.date
          this.challenge = response.data.challenge
          this.data = this.date.map((date, index) => ({
            x: new Date(date * 1000),
            y: this.challenge[index]
          }))
          const ctx =  document.getElementById([name]).getContext('2d')
          let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: 'Challenge',
                  data: this.data,
                  borderColor: ' #EA5455',
                }
              ]
            },
            options: {
              lineTension: 0,
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              scales: {
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    scaleLabel: {
                      display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true,
                      callback (value) {
                        return `${value}%`
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                xAxes: [
                  {
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                      unit: 'month'
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                      display: true,
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          })
        })
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="In order to display chart1">
    <chart-display>  <canvas slot="test1" id="chart_7" ></canvas> </chart-display>
  </div>
  <div class="In order to display chart1">
    <chart-display>  <canvas slot="test2" id="chart_8" ></canvas> </chart-display>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import chart-display from './Chart.vue'
export default {
  component: {chart-display}
}
</script>
```

As you can see i have shared my Chart.vue and App.vue, i am able to see my chart in the browser, but whenever i run the code or refresh the page, the charts flickers and stops. And then in my console i get below error:

[image]

Please someone help me to get rid of this issue, and please tell me if any changes i should do in my code to solve it. Please send me the modification code.

Comment: have you considered to use vue-chartjs?

Comment: Yeah, initially i tried using vue-chartjs but the charts were not displayed in the browser. So then i decided i will display charts by using chartjs

Comment: im using vue-chartjs at work without any issues. The error log says, `ctx` is null, check that the canvas element is really there first.

Comment: Can you please share me your vue-chartjs in code sandbox, i will just go through it, nd try to implement the same thing in my project.

Comment: should i define the canvas in data ?? Please tell me what changes i should do in my code in order get the results done

Comment: i can't share the enterprise code, but just following the docs should be enough. No, not in data. You can try to call `destroy()` (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy) on the component `beforeDestroy` hook.

Comment: No problem, but can you tell me what changes i should do in my code, so that the error doesn't come, please modify my code and send it to me.

Comment: create a sandbox, so i can look at the issue

Comment: Yeah i cannot do that, because i cannot share my actual API, so please look into my code and give me some solutions to solve it. I have shred my error also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, the charts are rendered twice. This causes flickering.

```js
// every time you use <chart-display>, 2 charts are rendered, this means chart 1 renders
// itself and chart 2, char 2 renders itself and chart 1, this is a bad pattern in Vue in general

mounted() {
  this.check(8, "chart_8");
  this.check(7, "chart_7");
}
```

Make the following changes:

**ChartDisplay.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div
    class="chart-container"
    style="position: relative; height: 40vh; width: 100%"
  >
    <canvas ref="chart_7"></canvas>
    <canvas ref="chart_8"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from "chart.js";
export default {
  name: "ChartDisplay",
  data() {
    return {
      date: [],
      challenge: [],
      data: [],
      // save charts in an array
      charts: [],
      // charts options
      options: {
        lineTension: 0,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              scaleLabel: {
                display: false,
              },
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                callback(value) {
                  return `${value}%`;
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          xAxes: [
            {
              type: "time",
              time: {
                unit: "month",
              },
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.render(7, this.$refs.chart_7);
    this.render(8, this.$refs.chart_8);
  },
  methods: {
    render(id, ctx) {
      this.fetchData(id).then((response) => {
        let data = response.date.map((date, index) => ({
          x: new Date(date * 1000),
          y: response.challenge[index],
        }));
        this.charts.push(
          new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "line",
            data: {
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: "Challenge",
                  data: data,
                  borderColor: " #EA5455",
                },
              ],
            },
            options: this.options,
          })
        );
      });
    },
    fetchData(id) {
      return this.$http.get(`/api_chart/${ id  }/full`);
    },
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.charts.forEach((chart) => chart.destroy());
  },
};
</script>
<style >
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

**App.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="In order to display chart1">
      <chart-display/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChartDisplay from "./ChartDisplay.vue";
export default {
  components: { ChartDisplay },
};
</script>
```

See it on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-bassi-7xnw2?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Can you please modify my code and send it to me, because I'm little confused right now. What i am trying to do is, i am trying to display two different charts by using API in methods. Because my charts are having same API but only differs in the endpoint i.e. ID in my case. Please modify my code and send it to me. @tuhin47 answer actually works for me but i am having the flickering issue with that.

Comment: Thank you @serg, i have gone through the fundamentals of Vuejs now i am understanding the flow of the code in Vuejs, so only i was bit confused when u answered me for the first time. And i tried the answer that you have updated, but don't know why it dint work out for me,  in console it says id undefined even though i have defined it. So what changes do you think that i should do. My only objective is to create one Chart.vue component instead of having separate charts component. Please tell me what i can do, by reviewing my code or your answer. It really helps me if you can tell me

Comment: @Quantum ok, I have updated my answer. Check, if it is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and updating the answer, this looks absolutely fine, but you asked me like why i was using the slots in my code, from your answer both the charts will be shown in the App.vue ie one after another, I want both the charts, but in my App.vue i am using many div's so i want chart one in first div and chart two in the fifith div that is the reason for using slots and then specifying canvas in App.vue. So you have got any idea, please do share me.

Comment: @Quantum glad to help. If you really want to use slots, i would suggest you to combine approaches from both answers. The answers provide already anything you need to get it work. Let me know, if there are still some issues.

Comment: Hello @serg, i tried the answer which you have updated, it is working fine, but i want to display a particular chart in a particular section of the App.vue, so here s how i tried to achieve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573051/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-in-c , i have shared you the issue that i face when i try to display the particular chart in App.vue. Please have a look and tell me where i am going wrong and if any changes i should do in Charts.vue (your updated answer). Even i tried slots and i get same error as shared in above link.

Comment: @Quantum I have seen your other questions. You are trying to display many charts. The first version of my answer already provides the most optimal solution. You have to create one Component that is responsible for charts rendering and pass props to it. Slots are not suited for this use case. take a look at another one [sansbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-bassi-7xnw2?file=/src/ChartDisplay.vue)

Answer (score 1):

I found several errors on your code. I fix them in [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-glitter-95x6d?file=/src/App.vue)

For **Chat.vue** :

- I rename the file as `ChartDisplay.vue` as similar as the component name
- import `chart.js` package for using `Chart()` function
- I use a demo API

```html
<template>
      <div
        class="chart-container"
        style="position: relative; height: 40vh; width: 100%"
      >
        <slot name="test1"></slot>
        <slot name="test2"></slot>
      </div>
    </template>

<script>
  import Chart from "chart.js";
  export default {
    name: "ChartDisplay",
    data() {
      return {
        date: [],
        challenge: [],
        data: [],
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.check(8, "chart_8");
      this.check(7, "chart_7");
    },
    methods: {
      check(id, name) {
        fetch(
            "https://api.wirespec.dev/wirespec/stackoverflow/fetchchartdataforvuejs"
          )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((response) => {
            this.date = response.date;
            this.challenge = response.challenge;
            this.data = this.date.map((date, index) => ({
              x: new Date(date * 1000),
              y: this.challenge[index],
            }));
            const ctx = document.getElementById([name]).getContext("2d");
            new Chart(ctx, {
              type: "line",
              data: {
                datasets: [{
                  label: "Challenge",
                  data: this.data,
                  borderColor: " #EA5455",
                }, ],
              },
              options: {
                lineTension: 0,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                    scaleLabel: {
                      display: false,
                    },
                    ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true,
                      callback(value) {
                        return `${value}%`;
                      },
                    },
                  }, ],
                  xAxes: [{
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                      unit: "month",
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                      display: true,
                    },
                  }, ],
                },
              },
            });
          });
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

For **App.vue**

- Your import should not carry any hyphen.
- `component` should be `components`
- render the component once to avoid flikering

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="In order to display chart1">
      <chart-display>
        <canvas slot="test1" id="chart_7"></canvas>
        <canvas slot="test2" id="chart_8"></canvas>
      </chart-display>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChartDisplay from "./ChartDisplay.vue";
  export default {
    components: {
      ChartDisplay
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: this does not solve the "flickering" issue, both charts are rerendered in `mounted` hook. That means first chart renders itself and the second one, and same for the second chart

Comment: Thanks a lot tuhin47, yeah only issue now is the flickering, whenever i run the code or refresh the page the charts flicker for several times and then it stops, so what can i do for that. Please give me some ideas for that.

Comment: I solved the flickering problem with some modification. Please check

Comment: @tuhin47 yes, this solves the flickering problem. But the original code in general has some dark patterns. This is not how one want to use Vue. Why `canvas` is passed as slot? Why it cannot be defined directly in the component? Why it renders 2 charts? and so on

Comment: Hello @tuhin47, i tried your answer, it worked fine, but the only issue i am facing right now is flickering of charts, it flickers several times and then it stops. I tried changing the life cycle hook also but that did not work out, and then i tried adding the beforeDestroy but nothing happened. As i am trying to display two charts, both the charts flickers when page is reloaded or when it runs for the first time. Please give me some ideas.