# How can I display desired/particular chart in App.vue from Charts.vue which contains different charts in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I am using Chartjs in order to display charts, I have created charts.vue component in which different charts are defined.

Here is my **Charts.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="chart-containr">
    <canvas ref="chart1"></canvas>
    <canvas ref="chart2"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
...
</script>
```

Here is my **App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="content-1">
    <charts/>  <-- Here i want to display my chart 1
  </div>

  ....

  <div class="content-8">
    <charts/>  <-- Here i want to display my chart 2
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import chart from './Charts'
exprt default{
  name: 'App',
  component: {chart}

    ....

}
```

As you can see in my App.vue, i have imported the Charts.vue and i have used charts as a component, but if i use it in the template part as  both the charts are display one after another. Rather i want chart1 in the 1st div and chart2 in the 8th div.

Please help me in this, i want to display particular chart from the charts.vue in different part of App.vue. I tried using props but dint work out.

Comment: Do you plan to have a lot of charts (`chart1`, `chart2` ...) or just a few ?

Comment: Yeah, i have more than 2 charts to display but i don't want one below the other, i wanna know how effectively a particular chart can be displayed in App.vue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably use a prop and interpolate the id on the component.

Charts.vue (should be renamed to Chart.vue in this way I guess)

```html
<template>
  <div class="chart-containr">
    <canvas :ref="`chart${chartId}`"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    chartId: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="content-1">
    <charts chart-id="1"></charts>
  </div>

  <div class="content-8">
    <charts chart-id="2"></charts>
  </div>
</template>
```

There is maybe also a way with slots but props will be enough here.
Btw, you could even `v-for` and display the `<charts>` component programmaticaly.

Comment: Hello @kissu, if i do it this way i get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, so you have any other ideas, please do tell me.

Comment: I will need some code/link to see what is happening here since you never showed any `length`-related code. Also, where does this error happen ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538183/flickering-of-charts-and-getcontext-error-with-chartjs-in-the-context-of-vuejs/65542871?noredirect=1#comment115897532_65542871 , the answer in there is what i am following to display the chart please have a look, and help me in this.