# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in chartjs with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I am trying to display particular chart in my App.vue from Charts.vue, Below is what I tried to achieve:

**Charts.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="chart-container">
    <canvas :ref="`chart${chartId}`"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    chartId: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  } 

  ....

}
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="content-1">
    <chart :chartId="1" />  <-- Here i want to display my chart 1
  </div>

  ....

  <div class="content-8">
    <chart :chartId="8" />  <-- Here i want to display my chart 2
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import chart from './Charts'
export default{
  name: 'App',
  component: {charts}

    ....

}
```

Nothing is displayed, and i get this error in my console:

[image]

But suppose if i declare as `<canvas ref="chart1"></canvas>` in template of Charts.vue and then if i just use `<charts/>` in my template of App.vue, then the chart is displayed.

Please do help me in order to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just a typo? - you are importing "chart", but using it as "charts".

Comment: That was by miss, i have updated my question, even though i get the same error