# JS - How to implement the YTD (Year To Date) logic in order to do Date selection

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I am trying to implement a method for a Date selection in vue-chartjs. Here is the function that i have used in the methods life cycle hook:

```
DateSelect(event) {
  const period = event.target.value
  let minValue = new Date(Math.max(...this.date) * 1000)
  const axisXMin = new Date(Math.min(...this.date) * 1000)

  switch (period) {
  case '1m':
    minValue.setMonth(minValue.getMonth() - 1)
    break
  case '3m':
    minValue.setMonth(minValue.getMonth() - 3)
    break
  case 'ytd':
    minValue.setFullYear(minValue.getFullYear() - minValue.getMonth())  //Here I want to implement the YTD Logic.
    break
  default:
    minValue = axisXMin
  }
  const data = this.data.filter(el => {
    return el.x >= minValue
  })
  this.GraphOutput(data) // this is vue-chartjs function.
}
```

Here the logic '1m' and '3m' works absolutely fine, as they display the previous 1month's and 3month's chart to the user when the respective button is clicked.

I want to know how to implement the YTD (Year to Date) Logic in the function that i have used above. Please do help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I understand you may need a full year of data in the graph. So that you need to set the minimum value as below:

```
case 'ytd':
    minValue.setYear(minValue.getFullYear() - 1);
    break
```

Comment: Hello @tuhin47, here what i found out , YTD – From beginning of the Year until day of Today. For example marking YTD: if today is June 26th, we'd want to flag all the dates of every year (not just this year) from January 1st until June 26th. In another definition: To calculate YTD, subtract its value on January 1st from its current value. Divide the difference by the value on January 1st. Multiply the result by 100 to convert the figure to a percentage. YTD is always of interest, but three-year and five-year returns tell you more. Please do help me, i am not getting this logic.

Comment: Hello @tuhin47, i got this by myself, can you please help me with this one, i am facing this from many days https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65933419/vuejs-unable-to-catch-the-axios-error-in-vue-cli-project